# CC-SA (without BY) has been "Retired", but I want to use it anyway. Recommendations?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

I would like to release some content (graphics, text, and print designs), letting people reuse them with or without modifications. I don't require attribution, but I do want modified versions to also be ShareAlike.

[Creative Commons has a "CC-SA" (no "BY")](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/sa/1.0/), but it's retired and not recommended for use.

[CreativeCommons just says it was retired for low usage](https://blog.creativecommons.org/2004/05/25/announcingandexplainingournew20licenses/), is there any reason I shouldn't use "CC-SA"? Is there a better alternative?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using the CC SA license is that it hasn't been updated since v1.0. The rest of the CC licenses are up to v4.0 now, and the new versions have cleared up a lot of issues and ambiguities in the legal text of the license.

One of the conditions of every ShareAlike license is that the person reusing the content must include a note mentioning the license. Given that they're going to be obligated to include a note no matter what, I don't think it's too much of a burden for anyone to also include attribution to you in their note. I'd recommend just using CC BY-SA.